# hasClass doesnt work in a variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to add a class where already have a class inside a var but it doesnt work and i cant find the right way of make it

**objective:**
If the class's inside the variable has a class called "clicado" as well, only add the class "selectedfiltrocor" to them but the one's with both class's "clicado" and the class inside the variable, if any of them as a class "clicado", add the class "selectedfiltrocor" to every class inside the variable

```js
if ($(filt2e4).hasClass("clicado")) {
            $(filt2e4).hasClass('clicado').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        } else {
            $(filt2e4).addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        }
```

someone can explain me why this doesnt work? and how i can make it right?

```js
var filt2e4 = $('.varcor2, .varcor2e1, .varcor2e2, .varcor2e3, .varcor2e4')

function clickclick() {    
$(filt2e4).hasClass("clicado").addClass("selectedfiltrocor");}
```

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #969696;
border: 1px solid #000000;
margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="varcor2 clicado"></div>
<div class="varcor2e1 clicado"></div>
<div class="varcor2e2"></div>
<div class="varcor2e3 clicado"></div>
<div class="varcor2e4"></div>

<div onclick="clickclick()"></div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Reading the documentation always is a good idea: [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass): _"The `.hasClass()` method will **return `true`** if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are."_

Comment: `filt2e4` is already a jQuery object. Wrapping it again in a jQuery object is needless.

Comment: `$(filt2e4).hasClass("clicado")` returns a `Boolean`(`true`/ `false`). Booleans don't have a  `addClass` method.